# Docker: Unable to run .net core api with docker-compose : exited with code 145

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, yaml

I am trying to run .net core api in a docker container but I am getting the following error:
[image]

My first guess looking at the error is that it's because it is not able to find .net core sdk. But as you can see I have included sdk in my dockerfile:
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
EXPOSE 80/tcp

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiForDocker.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  coreapi:    
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile      
    ports:
      - "4002:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved by removing :

```
  volumes:
      - .:/app
```

from my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  coreapi:    
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile      
    ports:
      - "4002:5000"
```

I guess the problem was that I building code with my dockerfile but then in docker compose I was basically saying that I want to use my source code outside to be used. It might work in nodejs but I am not sure how to use prebuilt .net code code as volume.